# Debugging with Eclipse JD - line mismatch

Tags: java, eclipse, decompiler, jadclipse, jd-eclipse

I have many classes with no source attached. I am using JD and it works just right in most cases, but in several files it shifts line realignments too much, starting from some point and keeps constant shift of X lines.
It is extremely annoying during the debugging, even with line number in the comments.

**Pic related** - please notice correct realignment till 398th line, then strange things happen and all the lines afterwards are shifted by 6.

[**Picture**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXbal.png)

Has anyone encountered that problem and knows the solution?

**Some additional info**:
 - Eclipse version - Luna
 - The same happens with JadClipse File Viewer
 - Disabling realignment makes everything much, much worse
 - I can't just attach the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have done my research and found Eclipse Class Decompiler:

http://www.cpupk.com/decompiler/

I fiddled with it for a moment and it solved my problems. It offers superior functionality compared to bare JD or Jadclipse.

Comment: By clicking on above link, I am getting 404 error. Here is the correct link - http://www.cpupk.com/decompiler/